# How to configure RealVNC to use dual displays full screen

Tags: linux, windows-7, vnc, display

The setup is the following:
VMWare ESXi5.0 Virtualisation server running a virtual machine Win7. This virtual machine is configured to have 2x Generic Non-PNP displays both at 1920x1200 resolution. The virtual machine runs fine, has RealVNC server 5.3.1 and I can get a VNC connection and remote desktop no problem.

The client machine is a Linux Mint desktop with 3x real displays, two of which are 1920x1200 resolution. This runs RealVNC Client 5.3. I can get a VNC window on the Win7 machine, but it is one big display 3840x1200 which can only be displayed fully when scaled and dragged across 2x client screens. This is messy and awkward and the scaling destroys the text.

Can anyone tell me how to configure the RealVNC server and client so the 2x displays of the Win7 machine display full-screen on the 2x displays on the client in full screen. I've spent ages reading the RealVNC docs, they're not good but do indicate this should be possible. The server does export both displays; but how to get the client to display them separately. I'm not sure if I need 2 server instances and/or two client instances for each display separately.

If required I'd consider using another VNC setup, but better the devil you know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No answers for 3 years.  Can we do it with windows 10?